# Folding long multiline messages triggers too early (expanding doesn't show more lines)

Tags: bug, chat

This is an example that just has happened in the *Ask Ubuntu General Room*.

You see a long multiline (code) message in the screenshot above. As last line, it shows the `(see full text)` link, so that means it got folded to occupy less space.

> [image: Screenshot of long post with "(see full text)" link]

But when you click the link to expand the folded message, you see that it actually did not hide any single line! It just added the link, but without really shortening the original message:

> [image: Screenshot of that same long post expanded (still same size)]

I think this is a bug, probably a typo in the part of the code where it gets checked whether a message is long enough to become folded.

This happens in all browsers I checked (Firefox 42 and Chromium 45; both on Ubuntu 15.10) and no matter whether I am logged in or view the chat room anonymously.

Please fix this, so that it only shows the `(see full text)` link when it really folds/hides lines of a message.

Comment: Do you have any chat userscripts that might be effecting this? Turn them off and see if the bug still exists (reload the page).

Comment: @ɥʇǝS Yes, with Greasemonkey disabled, I can still observe the same behaviour. I'm on Firefox 42.0 (Ubuntu 15.10). Could reproduce it also with a Chromium 45.0 browser without those add-ons and without logging into my account, just viewing the chat anonymously.